# What happens when I close the browser window during import?

Tags: product, import

I'm having an issue due probably to the import interruption and I would like to know what might go wrong in order to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not very clear, but this issue could be due to a PHP memory limit on your server?  Can you provide any additional information?

Comment: Basically I had to interrupt the import process and after that my front end had issues. It gives me an error (I've described it in my previous [post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59823/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-addtochildgroup-on-a-non-object-in-htd)) on the product detail page, which is related to the template I think. I am afraid that some table on the db was not updated correctly, to which the function addToChildGroup() might refer, so I was hoping there was a way to clean the db. But I'm just guessing, I have no clue, it's driving me quite crazy.

Comment: The other post looks like a compilation issue.  Do you have access to the server this site is running on?

Comment: Yes I can access the server.

Comment: I disabled compilation, as I have been suggested, but with no success.

Comment: can you do the following on the server: `cd /webroot/shell && php compiler.php clear` this will clear the disable and exclude the compiler path.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. I cannot access the server through the terminal, the site is on the hosting company server. Guess there is not much that I can do?